# Hamilton's pocket-book entry on quaternions

Tags: quaternions

I've long known the story of Hamilton carving the defining equations of the quaternions into the Broome (aka Brougham) Bridge, and have been aware for some years that there is no trace of the original carving. But I only recently read Hamilton's version of the story (told in a letter to his son Archibald), in which he wrote: "I pulled out on the spot a pocket-book, which still exists, and made an entry there and then."

I have a hard time believing Hamilton would have ever thrown the pocket-book away, and by the time he died, his reputation was sufficiently established that it seems unlikely that his heirs or the trustees of his estate could have been ignorant of its significance. So, do we know what happened to it?

Comment: [Trinity College Dublin](https://www.tcd.ie/library/manuscripts/blog/2013/06/to-go-boldly-hamilton-quaternions-and-space/) describes what it considers to be "probably" the note book in question.

Comment: Thanks! But I’m not sure on what grounds they say it’s “probably” the note book in question. Given the amount of writing on that page, it’s hard for me to imagine it coming from a notebook that would fit in Hamilton’s pocket.